# What were the 21 potential landing sites for the Mars 2020 mission?

Tags: mars, astrobiology, geology, perseverance, landing-site

In August 2015 more than 150 scientists attended a [conference to evaluate 21 potential landing sites](https://phys.org/news/2015-09-discusses-mars.html) for NASA's next rover, a mission called [Mars 2020.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mars_2020)

Out of those proposed landing sites the Mars 2020 Landing Site Steering Committee, appointed by NASA, came up with a list of 8 selected sites.
[A workshop held in February 2017 discussed these sites and narrowed the list down to 3 sites for further consideration.](https://marsnext.jpl.nasa.gov/workshops/wkshp_2017_02.cfm)

Because i'm interested in where on Mars past life could have existed, what were those initially proposed **21** landing sites in 2015 ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here they are, from the [letter summarizing the results of the 2015 workshop](https://marsnext.jpl.nasa.gov/workshops/2015_08/Final_Letter_for_Meyer_8-16-15.doc):

[image: 21 Mars 2020 landing sites]

The ancient habitable environment column sounds like what you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you, it seems that i searched not hard enough !

Comment: For presentations of the proposed landing sites: https://marsnext.jpl.nasa.gov/workshops/index.cfm