# Why the big difference between NASA and ESA/Roscosmos in evaluating the Oxia Planum landing site?

Tags: mars, landing, astrobiology, exomars, site-selection

In november 2018 [ESA announced that the **Oxia Planum region** is favoured](https://www.esa.int/spaceinvideos/Videos/2018/11/ESA_Euronews_Looking_for_life_on_Mars_with_ExoMars) for the [ExoMars surface mission.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ExoMars)

[image: Candidate landing sites]

The figure above from [this answer about the 21 potential landing sites](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/30743/what-were-the-21-potential-landing-sites-for-the-mars-2020-mission/30756#30756) for the [Mars 2020 mission](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mars_2020) shows that **Oxia Planum** was far below in the rank order.

**Question:** Why is there such a big difference in evaluating between [NASA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NASA) and [ESA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_Space_Agency)/[Roscosmos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roscosmos) ?

Comment: because the missions have different goals and requirments

Comment: @JCRM  If you could support your assertion with evidence, you would have a good answer !