# Which were the more than 60 (!) candidate locations for the Mars 2020 rover?

Tags: mars, planetary-science, perseverance, geology, landing-site

Four years ago I asked for the **21** potential landing sites for the Mars 2020 mission in [this question](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/30743/what-were-the-21-potential-landing-sites-for-the-mars-2020-mission), but now I've learned that there were more than **60** candidate locations !
From [NASA Announces Landing Site for Mars 2020 Rover](https://nasa.gov/press-release/nasa-announces-landing-site-for-mars-2020-rover):

> NASA has chosen Jezero Crater as the landing site for its upcoming Mars 2020 rover mission after a five year search, during which every available detail of more than 60 candidate locations on the Red Planet was scrutinized and debated by the mission team and the planetary science community.

Were those over 60 candidate locations recorded and/or described somewhere and can they still be tracked down ?

Answer (score 4):

Indeed, in [the introduction](https://marsnext.jpl.nasa.gov/workshops/2014_05/02_2020%20First%20Workshop%20Introduction%205-13-14.pdf) to [the first Mars 2020 Landing Site Workshop](https://marsnext.jpl.nasa.gov/workshops/index.cfm) that took place in May 2014, it was stated:

> - Multiple calls (Future Sites,2018,CDP) for future landing sites have resulted in **55 candidates plus an additional 9 candidates** for 2020 (multiple targets at many of these sites)

But [Appendix 6: Candidate Landing Site Supporting Information](https://mars.nasa.gov/mars2020/files/mars2020/SDT_Appendices_Final_v6.pdf) from the  [Report of the Mars 2020 Science Definition Team](https://researchgate.net/publication/259219062_Report_of_the_Mars_2020_Science_Definition_Team) already published in Juli 2013, shows table A6-1 with **over a hundred candidate landing sites** that were reviewed !